# How to check if order is refunded

Tags: orders, event-observer

I am new to Magento order status thing. I am observing event when order is refunded but not sure which event to use for the same.

I have few concerns about order refund

1. Does admin or customer refund the order ?
2. How can I know if the order is refunded ?
3. Does the customer raise a return request for refund ?

I need to perform some custom calculations when order is refunded.

For a specific scenario, is it possible to `Add some privilege amount to customer when order is Closed and if that order is refunded, restore that privilege amount ?`

Please Guide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your observer you can check the $order->getTotalCanceled() or getTotalRefunded() (or the getBaseTotalCanceled() and getBaseTotalRefunded()) to see if an order contains a refund or is canceled. A customer cannot cancel an order themself (only can cancel the payment that sets an order to canceled). You could use the event fired after saving an order to monitor the two fields above.

Refund and Cancel are both Admin actions. To cancel an order it cannot have a Paid or Pending invoice, to Refund an order you need to have a paid Invoice for the order.

For the adding and restoring a privilege amount you will have to add your own code to handle that, there is no default option to do this.

Comment: To check the creditmemo creation can I use `$order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED` ?

Comment: Closed is only used when the order is completely refunded, if only a few products are refunded check if the getTotalRefunded()>0 (same for canceled amount, but you could check for the order state to see if it is canceled)

Comment: If am working with only `Closed` condition, is the above true for me ?

Comment: Yes, the order state is set to closed if the order is completely refunded.

Answer (score 0):

1.**Does admin or customer refund the order**

in Magento  customer cannot directly send refund request. Customer only do  cancel a order.
Also magento,admin is manged refund managed by creating a credit memo.But cancel, credit memo is always depends on order status.

2.**How can I know if the order is refunded** 
if customer get order cancel and got a  email and then get order credit memo email. then we will know order is refunded.

**Import Note:** Credit Memo `creating is creating after order creating invoice`.It depends `on invoice amount`.Credit  memo `is Offline refund Process at magento`

**Process of refund :**

```
 1. order is completing it invoice. 
 2. then create credit memo.
```

If you have `creating on all item then after creating credit memo order goes to order complete`

Comment: Thanks for responding, but how customer can cancel an order as I do not see such button ? Also `is it possible to Add some privilege amount to customer when order is Closed and if that order is refunded, restore that privilege amount ?`

Comment: in customer account>order page you can see order cancel but it always depends order status. but magento don't provide refund button for a order